# Determine maximum Integer "null saved"

Tags: java, max

I need a final review and some tips about a function I wrote.

```
  public static Integer max(Integer... pNumber) {
    Integer lResult = null;
    for (Integer lNumber : pNumber) {
      if (lResult == null || (null != lNumber && lNumber > lResult)) {
        lResult = lNumber;
      }
    }
    return lResult;
  }
```

I am not realy sure if my code is elegant. 
null parameters as well as a null result is possible.
However... I have the feeling that I solved something in the code to complicated.
The function is part of an utility class which is used by the company. 
using third party librarys is not allowed.

Here the corresponding test:

```
@Test
public void testMaxWithInteger() {
  assertEquals(new Integer(9), NumberUtils.max(4, 2, -4, null, 9, 5));    
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is not only shorter and clearer, but faster `assertEquals(9, NumberUtils.max(4,2,-4,null,9,5));`

Comment: I seriously can not see why that would be too complicated. You have certain requirements and have to write the code to match it. You don't do anything else so there is no elegance to be gained by removing anything. Sure you can format it in different ways (like removing those silly prefixes from variable names :) ) but those are just personal/organization preferences.

Comment: I have removed the "new Integer(...)". That was the result of a mental diarrhea :-) .

Comment: @Vash: You meant to write Integer.valueOf(int). Parse is not a method in the Integer class.

Comment: You should avoid using new Integer(1); if you really must use Object then use Integer.valueOf(1); For Java below 1.5, if higher just use 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMHO I wouldn't use `null` objects as `Integer[]` can use 6x as much memory as using `int[]`

```
public static Integer max(Integer... ints) {
    long ret = Long.MIN_VALUE;
    for (Integer i: ints) 
      if (null != i && i > ret) 
        ret = i;
    return ret >= Integer.MIN_VALUE? (int) ret : null;
}
```

Instead of `Integer[]` I would use `int[]` and leave `0` or `Integer.MIN_VALUE` as my "un-initialised" value.

Comment: I love the hungarian notation part ;-)

Comment: @assylias Me too, so much I am removing them ;)

Comment: You've got an extra bracket

Comment: The fundamental point of the question was that null values have to be accounted for. You can not change the question just because you want to answer to be easier.

Comment: thank you very much. It is quite fascinating what can be done wrong.

Comment: `NullPointerException` if the first Integer is `null` in this code.

Comment: @Toben The OP asked about more elegant, less complicated solutions and using `int[]` would be simpler, and faster.  However, if its company library this might not be an option if you have existing code.

Comment: How does this work if Integer.MIN_VALUE and null are given as parameters?

Comment: @Torben It won't have *Long*.MIN_VALUE ;)

Comment: Yup. Took me a while to notice that data type. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid null check as @Peter suggested or by assigning the value to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`

```
public static Integer max(Integer... pNumber) {
    Integer lResult = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (Integer lNumber : pNumber) {
        if (lNumber == null) { //continue if null value encountered. 
            continue;
        }
        if (lNumber > lResult) {
            lResult = lNumber;
        }
    }
    return lResult;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Collections.max(Arrays.asList(pNumber));
```

Comment: Does it allow null parameters?

Comment: No it does not allow null values.

Comment: the test above would fail...
so I have to remove the null values?

Comment: That's a bit heavy operation, isn't it. You're basically executing "new Integer[...]; System.arraycopy(...);" only to find the largest integer in an array.